# Graph of the path of a projectile weirdly showing two separate lines

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, projectile

Ok, so I basically just plotted the path of a projectile (simple oblique projection, ignoring air resistance). After a while, an idea crept into my mind and I got to it:

Make the graph more dynamic by changing $ g=9.81 ms^{-2} $ to $g=\frac{GM}{(r+y)^2}$ where G is the Universal Gravitational Constant, M is the mass of the Earth, r is the radius of the Earth and y is just the y-coordinate (i.e., r+y is the distance from the center of the Earth).

The graph seemed perfectly normal when $u$ (magnitude of initial velocity) was small. But when I got to some really high speeds (I noticed it at $u=5500 ms^{-1}$), I saw *two lines*. One was the one expected and another was above it:

[image: graph at u=5500]

The problem line gets more easily noticeable as u increases. At $u =11200m/s$, it seems like:

[image: graph at u=11200]

Here is the graph's setup data:

[image: Graph's setup data]

After removing the $y \geq 0$ constraint, the graph seems like:

[image]

Now my question is that is this explainable via the laws of physics? Or is it just that the Graphing Calculator can't cope up with such a dynamic equation (using a variable that depends on y)? It seems quite weird to me, and that is why I am here for help.

The graph can be fiddled with [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/6mmharwnsm), if that would be of any help.

**Note:** The angle $a$ is in degrees

Comment: What are the axes of the plot showing?

Comment: @RC_23 The y-axis is the height and the x-axis is the horizontal distance

Comment: Your first equation assumes constant acceleration.  Replacing g with a variable acceleration does not produce a meaningful acceleartion. You can plot the resulting function but it does not represent the motion of a projectile.

Comment: @nasu I didn't quite get that. The acceleration due to gravity actually does depend on the height. So the path would not be perfectly parabolic, but would represent the path of the object projected, right?

Comment: Your first formula is just an approximation for constant g. If you consider the variation of g with the height you have to solve the differential equation of motion. The path is not a parabola but an ellipse, in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equation for the trajectory,
$$
y = x \tan a - \frac{g x^2}{2 u^2 \cos^2 a},
$$
is invalid if $g$ is not a constant.  To see this, recall that this equation is obtained by eliminating $t$ from the uniform-acceleration kinematic equations
$$
x = v_{x0} t \qquad y = v_{y0} t - \frac{1}{2} g t^2.
$$
Both of these, in turn, are obtained by assuming that
$$
\frac{d^2 x(t)}{dt^2} = 0 \qquad \frac{d^2 y(t)}{dt^2} = - g
$$
where $g$ is assumed to be a constant.

If $g$ is not a constant, this becomes much more difficult.  Effectively, you would now have
$$
\frac{d^2 y(t)}{dt^2} = - \frac{GM}{(r+y(t))^2}
$$
which is what's called an *ordinary differential equation* (ODE);  its solution is some function $y(t)$ whose second derivative is equal to the expression on the right-hand side for all $t$.  Describing the methods by which ODEs can be solved is an entire undergraduate-level math course, so I won't go into it here;  but suffice it to say that since the right-hand side now depends on $y(t)$ itself, it is much much more difficult to solve.

What Desmos is doing, meanwhile, is simply finding all of the points in the plane that satisfy the algebraic relation that you gave it.  But the algebraic relation you gave it does not have any relationship to the actual trajectory of a projectile.

Comment: Oh! Oops... I didn't really think of that! Thanks for clearing that out. And thanks for not going into the details of OEDs or I would have spent the entire night trying to understand them rather than doing homework!

Comment: I was trying to fiddle with the graph, and then I noticed something weird. When I kept angle as 60 degrees, the graph changes it nature around u=6500 approx from being a distorted parabola-like curve to a new shape of two curved lines. Also, for u=8000 and u=20000, the graph looks pretty much the same of two curved lines, which shouldn't be as in one the y component of velocity < escape vel and in another > esc vel. Why was u=6500 special, and why aren't u=8000 and u=20000 different??